# RAILS HOW TO CALCULATE TOTAL VALUE WITH FIELDS IN DIFFERENT TABLES

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Good night people. I'm new to rails and I'm using translate to post in English.

a question.
I have three tables: "ride_request_objects", "ata_objects" and "ride_requests".

They are related:
Model: ride_requests

```
has_many :ride_request_objects
has_many :ata_objects, through: :ride_request_objects
```

Model: ride_request_objects

```
belongs_to :ata_object
```

Model: ata_objects

```
has_many :ride_request_objects
has_many :ride_requests, through: :ride_request_objects
```

I need to calculate the "total" in "ride_request_objects", which would be:
ride_request_objects.quantity * ata_objects.unit_value

imagem da tabela:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWv1g.png

How can I do this iteration for the calculation? would it be inside the Model of "ride_request_objects"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want the total for each `RideRequest` object (ie. not a single total for all records).  If so then you can use a neat, almost hidden feature of ActiveRecord, where you can add arbitrary extra fields to a select and AR will automatically make them available as getters on the resulting objects, eg.

```
rrs = RideRequest.joins(:ata_objects).references(:ride_request_objects, :ata_objects).select( "ride_requests.*, SUM(ata_objects.unit_value * ride_request_objects.quantity) AS ata_sum").group(:id)
rrs.first.ata_sum
```